# How to modify an object property given its location within the object

Tags: javascript, object, reflection, pass-by-reference

Given an object `obj`, I can modify its properties by using something like `obj.a.b.c = "new value"`. However, I want to be able to do this programmatically, with the property's location in the form of an array. How can I make a function that looks like this:

`modifyProperty(obj, ["a", "b", "c"], "new value");`

and is equivalent to

`obj.a.b.c = "new value";`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for it, with a default object if no object is available.

```js
function modifyProperty(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();
    path.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!(a in r)) {
            r[a] = {};
        }
        return r[a];
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {};
modifyProperty(object, ["a", "b", "c"], "new value");
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function modifyProperty(obj, props, val) {
    var propName = props.pop();
    var o = props.reduce(function(obj, p) {
        return obj[p];
    }, obj);
    o[propName] = val;
}

var obj = {
   a: {b: {c: "old value"}}
}

modifyProperty(obj, ["a", "b", "c"], "new value");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the object values dynamically i have a code called `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` This will take an array of items which designate the properties of an array and the last one is the value. Such as

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var obj = {}.setNestedValue("a","b","c",100);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,null,2));
```

If instead of string arguments you use integers you get an array instead such as

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
      a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                           : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                             this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
                   : this[a[0]] = a[1];
      return this;
    };

    var obj = {}.setNestedValue("a",2 ,3,100);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,null,2));
```

Comment: Adding functionality to the builtin objects is... controversial. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea over on Programmers for some reasons why.