# Javascript - traverse tree like object and add a key

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have an object with depth-N like:

```
food = {
    'Non-Animal': {
        'Plants' : {
            'Vegetables': {
                ...
            }             
        },
            'Minerals' : {
                ...
            }
        },
    'Animal': {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to add in this object the category 'Fruits', but I have to search the object where 'Plants' are and then add it. So I don't want to do in one statement:

```
food['Non-Animal']['Plants']['Fruits'] = {};
```

Since I want to search first where it belongs.

How can I add the fruits category to the object while iterating through it? What I have so far is:

```
addCategory(food, category, parent);

function addCategory(obj, category, parent_name) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (key == parent_name) {
            obj[key][category] = {};
        }
        var p = obj[key];
        if (typeof p === 'object') {
            addCategory(p, category, parent);
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this routine to do this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39300560/4543207)

Comment: watch out using `typeof p === 'object'` cause if `p` is any type of object, such as an `array`, this will be true.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you'd want your function to define a variadic parameter that takes individual names of the path you wish to traverse and create if necessary.

Using `.reduce()` for this makes it pretty easy.

```js
const food = {
  'Non-Animal': {
    'Plants': {
      'Vegetables': {}
    },
    'Minerals': {}
  },
  'Animal': {}
}

console.log(addCategory(food, "Non-Animal", "Plants", "Fruits"));
console.log(addCategory(food, "Non-Animal", "Minerals", "Gold"));

function addCategory(obj, ...path) {
  return path.reduce((curr, name) => {
    if (!curr) return null;
    if (!curr[name]) return (curr[name] = {});
    return curr[name];

    // More terse but perhaps less readable
    // return curr ? curr[name] ? curr[name] : (curr[name]={}) : null; 
  }, obj);  
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(food, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine. However you might want to terminate after adding the prop:

```
function addCategory(obj, category, parent_name) {
   for (var key in obj) {
      if (key == parent_name){
       return obj[key][category] = {};
      }
      var p = obj[key];
      if (typeof p === 'object') {
        if(addCategory(p, category, parent)) return true;
      } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see only one mistake: The recursive call of addCategory cannot find the parent-variable, cause it's called parent_name in your scope.

```js
var food = {
  'Non-Animal': {
    'Plants' : {
      'Vegetables': {
       }
    },
    'Minerals' : {}
  },
  'Animal': {}
}

function addCategory(obj, category, parent_name) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key == parent_name){
      obj[key][category] = {};
    }
    var p = obj[key];
    if (typeof p === 'object') {
      addCategory(p, category, parent_name);
    } else {

    }
  }
}

console.log(food);
addCategory(food, 'Fruits', 'Plants');
console.log(food);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to create function that will take key as string and object as value that you want to assign to some nested object.

```js
var food = {"Non-Animal":{"Plants":{"Vegetables":{}},"Minerals":{}},"Animal":{}}

function add(key, value, object) {
  key.split('.').reduce(function(r, e, i, arr) {
    if(r[e] && i == arr.length - 1) Object.assign(r[e], value);
    return r[e]
  }, object)
}

add('Non-Animal.Plants', {'Fruits': {}}, food)
console.log(food)
```